# How to add arguments to a Java application

Tags: java

I want to add arguments to my Java application before i run it. I want to be able do somthing like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String document = args[0];
    new DocumentViewer(document);
}
```

I want to do somthing like when you click on a Word document it opens up the document by itself, you dont have to open word and then click open. Does anyone know how to add arguments? All relevant answers are appriciated!

Comment: What kind of application is it? Do you run it from the command line?

Comment: The application shows a document that you can edit and save, kind of like word, i want to be able to click on the file and have the text passed as an argument so that i can start the program up with the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java YourClass yourfile.xtx
```

To associate your program with a file extension, so that it is automatically called, you have to configure your Desktop Environment (Linux) or Windows (Windows) (I don't know for OSX).

I don't have it in my head, but as far as I remember, you combine the extension, xtx for example, with a starting command, like

```
java -cp C:\Programs\yourlibs\your.jar YourClass %1%
```

If you have or can have more arguments (mark multiple files, and drag them to your starter) you can, afaik, go up to %9%:

```
java -cp C:\Programs\yourlibs\your.jar YourClass %1% %2% %3%
```

%1% is for the first param and so on. 
There is nothing you can do from Java, except catching those parameter, what you already do.

On Linux, your starter is very similar:

```
java -cp /usr/local/lib/your.jar YourClass $1 $2 $3
```

Comment: ok so lets say i have an executable jar named program.jar and i am running it on a windows based computer, how could i make windows open program.jar with the argument of the contents of the file, how could i do this?

Comment: Is the jarfile the problem, or the new idea, to pass the content of the file? From the command line `type file | java -jar your.jar` passes the content instead of the filename, or with the filename `java -jar your.jar file`. In the first case, you have to read from stdin (... `= new BufferedReader (System.in));`. But you don't want to start your program with the content of the text file as arguments - I don't know the limit, but I can't imagine to read more than some thousands of words from the arguments.

Comment: I want to pass the contents of the file as an argument

Comment: On linux, this is `java YourClass $(cat file)`, but would pass the content as one argument per word. `java YourClass "$(cat file)"`, might help. as long as there aren't any hyphens in the file itself. Why do you want to do that? It's a new question, so can you open a new question?

Comment: I think you gave me what i needed, Ive got a good idea of what i want to do, thanks!

Comment: @John, why don't you just open the file passed as an argument in an initializing block of your application and use its content from there??

Answer (score 3):

If you're launching your app from the command line you could just pass the arguments separated by a blank space right after the application name like this:

```
java name_app arg1 arg2 etc...
//the code above passes to name_app 3 strings: "arg1", "arg2", and "etc..."
```

Not sure about what you want to do with Word but I hope this was helpful.

Comment: How would i do it differently if i were running a jar?

Comment: @John `java -jar name_jar arg1 arg2 etc.`

Answer (score 1):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)

> ..JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, **file associations**, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

For a demo. of the file associations, see the [JNLP API file service demo](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Answer (score 0):

The application that you are trying to create is a GUI application while the arguments that main method take is meant for Command Line interface input.

Where string [] args is the String array that can story many arguments from CLI. Of course you can implement the feature with a mix of CLI and GUI program but then you will be limited to launch your application from CLI, which doesn't make sense.

Another workaround can be. Create a demo frame that appears in the beginning have some textboxes and let users enter what you want to take as an argument, pass that value in the method, or data types you like. In that way you can have a full blown GUI application.